# Page faults monitor for Windows

Tags: windows, profiling

Is there any tool which displays at runtime, Page Faults delta on a per thread basis? Basically I have an application that is causing lots of page faults and I want to nail down the thread which is causing the maximum.

Comment: Were you able to find any good debugging tools to deal with that?  I have an application like that and I just discovered it's getting a ton of Page Faults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really doubt you could nail down page faults to threads a process page faults not a thread.  Surely though its going to be the busiest thread in terms of either CPU or may be Context switches that you would want to look at.

I use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for this sort of diagnosis.  Open the properties on your application and select the threads tab.

Comment: The fault itself occurs in a very specific context, actually. Perhaps Windows doesn't keep track of how many page faults occur in each individual thread, but that doesn't change the fact that those page faults did occur in specific threads.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xperf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305210.aspx). It aggregates ETW events & lets you drill down to find out which process/thread/function is responsible for most cpu/memalloc/diskops/faults etc.