# Why is the second loop over a static array in the BSS faster than the first?

Tags: c, loops, gcc, optimization, for-loop

I have the following code that writes a global array with zeros twice, once forward and once backward.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100000000

char c[SIZE];
char c2[SIZE];

int main()
{
   int i;
   clock_t t = clock();
   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       c[i] = 0;

   t = clock() - t;
   printf("%d\n\n", t);

   t = clock(); 
   for(i = SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      c[i] = 0;

   t = clock() - t;
   printf("%d\n\n", t);
}
```

I've run it a couple and the second print is always showing a smaller value...

However, if I change change c to c2 in one of the loops, the time difference between both prints becomes negligible... what is the reason for that difference?

EDIT:

I've tried compiling with -O3 and looked into the assembly: **there were 2 calls to memset** but the second was still printing a smaller value.

Comment: Just a guess: the first loops pages things in. The second loop benefits from that.

Comment: This likely has to do with a cache optimization. Or the compiler may be intelligent enough to realize the second loop is essentially a NOP when it's done on the same array and optimize it away. But more likely a caching effect.

Comment: I don't suppose you tried running the second loop *first* and gauged the results from that as well.

Comment: Oh.. I hadn't try that... I was thinking that maybe the compiler would have figured out that in the second time it was already set to 0 and did things in a shorter way

Comment: I'm surprised that the compiler didn't optimize *both* loops into nops since objects of static storage duration are zero-initialized anyway.

Comment: I didn't check the .s file deeply (I'm not that good at assembly) but I saw that it inserted the memset and called it twice

Comment: @T.C.: since the `c[]` is global it is accessible by external functions such as `clock()` and `printf()`. The compiler can't elide the loops' side effects.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ah, good point, though it looks like GCC didn't elide `memset` even if they are declared `static`.

Comment: what's the typedef of `clock_t` in your system? If it's `long` then maybe you have undefined behavior in your code

Comment: `clock_t` might not be `int`. It could even be `double`. You'll need to cast the result to match the format specifier you choose in `printf` to ensure well-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you defined some global data in C, it is zero-initialized:

```
char c[SIZE];
char c2[SIZE];
```

In linux (unix) world this means, than both `c` and `c2` will be allocated in special ELF file section, the [`.bss`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss):

> ... data segment containing statically-allocated variables represented solely by zero-valued bits initially

The `.bss` segment is created to not store all zeroes in the binary, it just says something like "this program wants to have 200MB of zeroed memory".

When you program is loaded, ELF loader (kernel in case of classic static binaries, or `ld.so` dynamic loader also known as `interp`) will allocate the memory for `.bss`, usually like something like [`mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag and READ+WRITE permissions/protection request.

But memory manager in the OS kernel will not give you all 200 MB of zero memory. Instead it will mark part of virtual memory of your process as zero-initialized, and every page of this memory will point to the special zero page in physical memory. This page has 4096 bytes of zero byte, so if you are reading from `c` or `c2`, you will get zero bytes; and this mechanism allow kernel cut down memory requirements.

The mappings to zero page are special; they are marked (in [page table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table)) as read-only. When you do *first* write to the any of such virtual pages, the [General protection fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault) or [pagefault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) exception will be generated by hardware (I'll say, by MMU and TLB). This fault will be handled by kernel, and in your case, by [minor pagefault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault#Minor) handler. It will allocate one physical page, fill it by zero bytes, and reset mapping of just-accesed virtual page to this physical page. Then it will rerun faulted instruction.

I converted your code a bit (both loops are moved to separate function):

```
$ cat b.c
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100000000

char c[SIZE];
char c2[SIZE];

void FIRST()
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       c[i] = 0;
}

void SECOND()
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       c[i] = 0;
}


int main()
{
   int i;
   clock_t t = clock();
   FIRST();
   t = clock() - t;
   printf("%d\n\n", t);

   t = clock(); 
   SECOND();

   t = clock() - t;
   printf("%d\n\n", t);
}
```

Compile with `gcc b.c -fno-inline -O2 -o b`, then run under linux's `perf stat` or more generic `/usr/bin/time` to get pagefault count:

```
$ perf stat ./b
139599

93283


 Performance counter stats for './b':
 ....
            24 550 page-faults               #    0,100 M/sec           


$ /usr/bin/time ./b
234246

92754

Command exited with non-zero status 7
0.18user 0.15system 0:00.34elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 98136maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+24576minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

So, we have 24,5 thousands of minor pagefaults. With standard page size on x86/x86_64 of 4096 this is near 100 megabytes.

With `perf record`/`perf report` linux profiler we can find, where pagefaults occur (are generated):

```
$ perf record -e page-faults ./b
...skip some spam from non-root run of perf...
213322

97841

[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.018 MB perf.data (~801 samples) ]

$ perf report -n |cat
...
# Samples: 467  of event 'page-faults'
# Event count (approx.): 24583
#
# Overhead       Samples  Command      Shared Object                   Symbol
# ........  ............  .......  .................  .......................
#
    98.73%           459        b  b                  [.] FIRST              
     0.81%             1        b  libc-2.19.so       [.] __new_exitfn       
     0.35%             1        b  ld-2.19.so         [.] _dl_map_object_deps
     0.07%             1        b  ld-2.19.so         [.] brk                
     ....
```

So, now we can see, that only `FIRST` function generates pagefaults (on first write to bss pages), and `SECOND` does not generate any. Every pagefault corresponds to some work, done by OS kernel, and this work is done only one time per page of bss (because bss is not unmapped and remapped back).

Comment: good explanation, I can't try it tho.. I use gcc but I'm on windows, nor my system or I have a clue of what is perf.

Comment: nightshade, [`perf` is linux profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux)). Basically Windows implements bss in similar way, with the same idea of pagefaults, as said in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault. Some MS pages about topic... http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/06/10/the-basics-of-page-faults.aspx. Sorry, but I can name some tool in windows which will allow you to monitor pagefaults and map them to some function of your program. You can use task manager or [Process Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) to monitor pagefaults in real time.

Comment: But all what you want to know: first write access to data (first touch) is more expensive than any other access. In case of zero-initialized data (or sometimes malloced data), it is cost of page fault, allocating some physical page and filling it with zeroes. In case of some static data, it is the cost of loading data from disk into memory (if it was not loaded at time of access) on read, and implementing Copy-on-write on writing to static data.

Comment: Q about pagefault monitoring: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781285/page-faults-monitor-for-windows. Some secret tools from MS (pfmon.exe): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958290.aspx. According to http://smartbear.com/forums/f59/fp7/t46603/hard-and-soft-page-faults/ AQTime profiler (free trial or 600 USD $$$) is capable of profiling code which generates pagefaults.

Answer (score 5):

Following asimes answer that it's due to caching - i'm not convinced that you can enjoy the benefit of caches with a ~100M array, you're likely to completely thrash out any useful data before returning there.

However, depending on your platform (OS mostly), there are other mechanisms as work - when you allocate the arrays you never initialize them, so the first loop probably incurs the penalty of the first access per each 4k page. This usually would cause some assist of a syscall that comes with a high overhead.
In this case you also modify the page, so most system would be forced to perform a copy-on-write flow (an optimization that works as long as you read only from a page), this is even heavier.

Adding a small access per page (which should be negligible with regards to actual caching and it only fetches one 64B line out of each 4k page), managed to make the results more even on my system (although this form of measurement isn't very accurate to begin with)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100000000

char c[SIZE];
char c2[SIZE];

int main()
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i+=4096)      ////  access and modify each page once
       c[i] = 0;                      ////

   clock_t t = clock();

   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       c[i] = 0;

   t = clock() - t;
   printf("%d\n\n", t);

   t = clock(); 
   for(i = SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      c[i] = 0;

   t = clock() - t;
   printf("%d\n\n", t);
}
```

Comment: "*probably incurs the penalty of the first access per each 4k page*" - usually it is called "minor pagefault" in Linux (not with syscall, but with hardware-generated exception/interrupt [GPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault)), and its count is reported by `/usr/bin/time` and by `perf stat`

Comment: @osgx: It's also sometimes known as an assist. Good point about profiling, but we'll have to pay the same penalty once anyway, the only question is if it's within the timed section or not.

Comment: `perf stat` and /usr/bin/time is not profiling, it is just counting of total ### of event, the pagefault in our case. We can add third loop (or switch second loop to `c2` array) and check changes in the minor pagefault counter.

Comment: I tried out the code you posted there, and got `272248`, `273263`. However, as you mentioned this is inaccurate, if I run it a few times in a row the two loops take turns being faster than one another, essentially the penalty is incurred before the timing as you posted it

Comment: Thanks for the cache hint.. I brought the question here because me and a friend were trying to compare some different ways to initialize an array (trying to see how close we would get to memset) with all positions having the same value: we tried some things such as using a pointer to long to fill 8 chars at a time... then when inverted the loop and got this difference in the results I got curious

Comment: Inversion of the loop is not the cause here. I think, there can be some not-popular way of allocating prefaulted memory in Windows... In linux there is [`madvise`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) which may help (and may not), and some kernel [patches](http://lwn.net/Articles/127301/) from SGI. Or just do write touch of every page before doing any benchmarking.

Answer (score 3):

If you modify the second loop to be identical to the first the effect is the same, the second loop is faster:

```
int main() {
   int i;

   clock_t t = clock();
   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
       c[i] = 0;
   t = clock() - t;
   printf("%d\n\n", t);

   t = clock(); 
   for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
      c[i] = 0;
   t = clock() - t;
   printf("%d\n\n", t);
}
```

This is due to the first loop loading the information into the cache and that information being readily accessible during the second loop

Results of the above:

```
317841
277270
```

**Edit**: Leeor brings up a good point, `c` does not fit in the cache. I have an Intel Core i7 processor: http://ark.intel.com/products/37147/Intel-Core-i7-920-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI

According to the link, this means the L3 cache is only 8 MB, or 8,388,608 bytes and `c` is 100,000,000 bytes

Comment: Wow, you have a pretty big cache then :)

Comment: It's a good starting point though, and applies on 99% of these questions. At first I though there's still useful caching for the pagetable at least, but the number of pages won't fit in any TLB i've ever seen. I have another theory though, see below